# Why they say a character string consists of up to eight characters in NASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

The [NASM manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html) says:

> 3.4.2 Character Strings
>
> **A character string consists of up to eight characters** enclosed in
> either single quotes ('...'), double quotes ("...") or backquotes
> (`...
> `). Single or double quotes are equivalent to NASM (except of
> course that surrounding the constant with single quotes allows double
> quotes to appear within it and vice versa); the contents of those are
> represented verbatim. Strings enclosed in backquotes support C-style
> \–escapes for special characters.

I don't understand why they say that a character string consists of up to eight characters, does that mean if a character string consists of 9 characters, it is not called a character string?!

Comment: Yes, you only need to read 2 more subsections, to [3.4.4 String Constants](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.4) which says _"A string constant looks like a character constant, only longer"_

Answer (score 5):

It all stemmed from this

```
sub al, '0'
```

the ability to use characters as immediate to hugely improve code readability.

From that the successive steps were immediate<sup>1</sup>:

```
sub al, '0'
sub ax, '00'
sub eax, '0000' 
sub rax, '00000000'
```

NASM is not really picky in the delimiting character as the documentation clarified (I use single quotes for characters and double quotes for strings but it's just my personal taste).

Note that a character string generates a numeric immediate where the leftmost characters are placed in the least significant bytes.
`mov rbx, '01234567'` corresponds to `mov rbx,0x3736353433323130`, the rationale being that when that value is stored in memory one gets the exact character string typed.

Also, note that it is the context that tells strings and character strings apart:

> A character constant consists of a string up to eight bytes long, used in an expression context. It is treated as if it was an integer.

```
 MY_SYMBOL EQU 'abcd'          ;Character string
 MY_VAR    dw  'abcd'          ;String

 mov eax, MY_SYMBOL            ;mov eax, 64636261h
 mov eax, MY_VAR               ;mov eax, address_of(MY_VAR)
 mov eax, 'cdef'*2             ;Character string
```

because they syntactically overlap.

---

<sup>1</sup> No pun intended